# How to pass argument to Neoformat for prettier-eslint-cli from a variable in vimrc

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I have the following line of code:

```
  autocmd FileType javascript execute "setlocal formatprg=".g:prettier_eslint_path2."\\ --eslint-config-path" . g:eslintrc_full_path ."\\"
```

I can see this when I start vim in the directory which has `.eslintrc`:

```
ESLINTRC PATH
.eslintrc
Prettier ESLINT PATH
/Users/localuser/lendi/lendi-app/node_modules/.bin/prettier-eslint^@
/Users/localuser/lendi/lendi-app/node_modules/.bin/prettier-eslint
Has  ESLINTRC
/Users/localuser/lendi/lendi-app/.eslintrc
--- Auto-Commands ---
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I have the `g:eslintrc_full_path` logged out correctly, how do I pass it from the variable to formatprg correctly.

If I remove the args, I get an empty output as the result of the file.

If I remove the `\\` it informs that it is valid to do so.

I dont understand how to pass arguments to the cli script when using a variable. I did not find any examples of string interpolation when reading through http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/26.html

Also, the following code also causes a problem:

```
  autocmd FileType javascript execute "setlocal formatprg=".g:prettier_eslint_path2."\\ --eslint-config-path\\ ".g:eslintrc_full_path
```

and deletes the entire file. I have tried:

```
  autocmd FileType javascript execute "setlocal formatprg=".g:prettier_eslint_path2."\\ --eslint-config-path\\ ".g:eslintrc_full_path
```

but it deletes the contents of the file as well.

I have tried it with only `--stdin` like this but it fails and converts everything to double quotes:

```
  autocmd FileType javascript execute "setlocal formatprg=".g:prettier_eslint_path2."\\ --stdin"
```

I have tried adding in the single quote as an argument here but it still converts everything to double-quotes.

```
autocmd FileType javascript let &l:formatprg= g:prettier_eslint_path2."\\ --single-quote\\ --eslint-config-path\\ ". g:eslintrc_full_path
```

Also, logging `&l:formatprg` does not work:

```
autocmd FileType javascript let &l:formatprg = g:prettier_eslint_path2.' --single-quote --eslint-config-path '. g:eslintrc_full_path
echom &l:formatprg
```

I tried checking the messages:

and it shows:

/Users/localuser/lendi/lendi-app/node_modules/.bin/prettier-eslint --single-quote --write --eslint-config-path /Users/localuser/lendi/lendi-app/.eslintrc

which should work. How does neoformat pass the file to the cli script.

How do I solve this problem?

I have also created a issue on `neoformat` for the same:

https://github.com/sbdchd/neoformat/issues/112

Comment: please, do not open issues for basic usage questions in various repositories at the same time.

Comment: You mention Neoformat in the title of your question, but the entire content appears to be about using Vim's builtin `'formatprg'`. For help using Neoformat, I suggest reading `:help neoformat.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is an escaping problem, you should use:

```
autocmd FileType javascript setlocal formatprg=command\ --arg
```

Or if you need variables:

```
autocmd FileType javascript let &l:formatprg = 'command ' . l:arg
```

---

**Update**: As [commented by the plugin owner](https://github.com/sbdchd/neoformat/issues/112#issuecomment-324322355), it would be easier to [define a formatter](https://github.com/sbdchd/neoformat#config-optional) via Neoformat:

```
let g:neoformat_javascript_eslint = {
            \ 'exe': 'eslint',
            \ 'args': [],
            \ }

let g:neoformat_enabled_javascript = ['eslint']
```

But if you want to keep using `formatprg`, you should get rid of the `FileType` auto command and put `setlocal {option}` or `let &l:{option}` directly in `ftplugin/javascript.vim`, see [`:help filetype-plugin`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_43.txt.html#filetype-plugin).

Comment: I have tried `autocmd FileType javascript let &l:formatprg= g:prettier_eslint_path2."\\ --single-quote\\ --eslint-config-path\\ ". g:eslintrc_full_path`

but it still wont work.

Comment: Try removing the backslashes, spaces are already escaped within quotes. The result of `\\ ` is `\ `, not a space.

Comment: I removed the `\\` and left the spaces in there and the result is that it deletes the contents of the file and saves the file.

Comment: Then it might indeed be related to the eslint command or the neoformat plugin. Does the same thing happen when you execute the formatting command without vim (from terminal)?

Comment: No, from terminal I execute `./node_modules/.bin/prettier-eslint --write ./app/routes.js --eslint-config-path ./.eslintrc` and it works correctly

Comment: Then the last thing I can think of is to check `echo &l:formatprg` outputs this exact command in JS files. If it does, it probably is a plugin or configuration issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64162/discussion-between-vamsiampolu-and-lei).

Answer (score 0):

When using the `formatprg` option, Vim passes the file contents to the external program on `stdin`. (See `:help 'formatprg'`)

You are not telling prettier-eslint-cli to expect to receive input in this way, and so the command fails.

The [README for prettier-eslint-cli](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-eslint-cli) explains how to use it from Vim:

> Vim users can add the following to their .vimrc:
>
> autocmd FileType javascript set formatprg=prettier-eslint\ ***--stdin***

*(Emphasis mine)*

You also want to specify the paths of the executable and rcfile, so you need to amend this to add these in, whilst continuing to pass the necessary `--stdin` option.

```
autocmd FileType javascript let &l:formatprg = g:prettier_eslint_path2.' --stdin --eslint-config-path '. g:eslintrc_full_path
```